# How to prove "rank is not less than the number of non-zero eigenvalues"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know to prove this using core-nilpotent decomposition. But if it feels like using a big tool for a small problem, is there any other better, simple proofs?

Comment: You can easily prove it by taking vector bundles over zero-dimensional manifolds and applying the Atiyah-Singer index theorem ;)

Comment: nice!!, I just wanted to press that it was not a HW problem,which is why first statement was there!! :):).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ corresponds to an eigenvector $v_i$ such that $A_iv_i=\lambda v_i$. Moreover it is easy to show that the $v_i$ are independent. So the rank has to be at least the number of such vectors.

Comment: Probably worth to add that $Av=\lambda v$ implies that $v\in\mathcal{R}(A)$, so that the span of these $v$'s forms a subspace of $\mathcal{R}(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

The  linear spaces spanned by the eigenvectors of non-equal eigenvalues are  <s>orthogonal</s> linearly independent, so the image has at least the dimension of the numbers of eigenvalues.

Comment: Nitpick: Independent, but not in general orthogonal. (There is no assumption of symmetry.)

Comment: Of course you are right. I thought of the hermitian case.